# stripe test card number is valid in live mode

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I set to publish and secret keys in live mode. but when I use the 42424242424242 card number, it's valid. I don't find any solution, how to fix it.

```php
$options = [
   'amount' => \floatval($req->cost) * 100,
   'currency' => 'aud',
   'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
];            
$stripKey = \Utility::isLocalHost() ? $_ENV["STRIP_SECRET_KEY"] : $_ENV["STRIP_SECRET_KEY_lIVE"];
Stripe::setApiKey($stripKey);
$intent = PaymentIntent::create($options);
```

as you can see, my backend is written in PHP language that generates a client secrete key and in front-end, I build an element and stripe form by that key.

```js
this.strip = Stripe(this.key);
const options = { clientSecret: payment.clientSecret };
this.stripElement = this.strip.elements(options);
const paymentElement = this.stripElement.create('payment');
paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
paymentElement.on('change', (event) => {
if (event.complete && !event.empty) {
   this.submitBtn.disabled = false;
 }
});
```

However, I move the code on my server and set the live mode for stripe. The test credit card '42424 ...' is still valid.
[image]

Comment: may be the issue with the way you are setting your Stripe API key

Comment: Then try to buy with it...

Comment: I found the problem. the problem was in my ajax request before confirming payment.